# Asymptotic controllability of linear in phase system

Tags: control-theory

Suppose we have $\dot x= F(t, u)x$ for $x\in\Bbb R^n$ and $F$ a continuous matrix in $t$ and $u$. In fact, in my case, there exists a smooth $f(t)$ s.t. $F(t, u)$ is invertible whenever $u \neq f(t)$. Is anything known about the controllability of this system near 0? In particular, when can we drive an initial $x_0\neq 0$ to some vector subspace $V\subset \Bbb R^n$ in finite time? In my case, $x_0$ can be scaled to any magnitude if necessary.

I found some papers online regarding something called the Sussman condition, which states that, if the system satisfies certain hypotheses, for any $t$ there exists a control $u$ which can drive the ball $B_\delta$ to $B_\epsilon$ in time $t$ for $\delta$ and $\epsilon$ small enough. This would more than suffice for my purposes, but there is no point in checking the conditions because a linear system cannot be driven to the origin with nice controls. Are there any known results on the matter? Could someone share some references?

Comment: What if $F = 0$? You will need more conditions than only continuity. And what do you mean with *"a linear system cannot be driven to the origin with nice controls"*? Linear state feedback is not nice? Why?

Comment: @SampleTime you are correct. I should have added that for my case, there exists a smooth $f(t)$ s.t. $F(t, u)$ is invertible whenever $u(t) \neq f(t)$. Regarding my claim, I think that if the system can be driven to $0$ at time $t_1$, the time-reversed system $\dot y = -F(-t, u)y$ would have a non trivial solution with initiail conditions $y(t_1) = 0$, which is impossible for a continuous coefficient matrix.